# Can you cut self leveling concrete with a concrete saw?

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete

I am looking to remodel a basement and I really like the concrete finish look with a clear coat of opaque epoxy over the top. I don't want the floor to be one continuous piece. Its an older home with crappy looking concrete on the base floor. I want to pour the self leveling concrete, cut 4x4 "relief cuts" and then put clear/opaque epoxy over the top.

If I used a concrete saw to cut the self leveling concrete would it chip/break? Overall how does the idea sound?

Comment: which concrete finish look?  Brushed, wood float, steel float, magnesium float, polshed?

Comment: Does the finish matter to whether SLC would crack @Jasen? Honest question, I haven't a clue...

Comment: What does "clear coat of opaque epoxy" mean? "Clear" and "Opaque" have literally opposite meanings. Do you mean "[Translucent](https://www.google.com/search?q=Translucent&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS991US993&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" instead of "[Opaque](https://www.google.com/search?q=Opaque&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS991US993&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)"?

Comment: no, but you may not end up with what you want